# Assigning the value based on a matched condition to another variable

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to write something like this in R:

```
If (df$age<5) {df$child=1}
else {df$child=NA}
```

But its not working for me.

Can you please correct it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to place the closing `}` of the if on the same line as the next `else`, so try it this way:

```
child <- NA
If (age<5) child <- 1
```

Since you are operating on a vector, you should better use `ifelse`:

```
df$child <- ifelse(df$age < 5, 1, NA)
```

Or better (syntax sugar) using `ifelse` with `transform`:

```
transform(df,child = ifelse(age<5, 1 ,NA))
```

Comment: Is it necessary to run the loop for all records? to check on value?

Comment: You have to provide some more content. I don't know what you mean with "all records". You could post a sample of your data and expected outcome in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`if` , `else` will not work with vector. You should use `ifelse` :

```
df$child <- ifelse(df$age<5, 1 ,NA)
```

In case you dela with scalars, here the R way to write `if`, `else` statement:

```
age <- 2
x <- if(age<5) 1 else NA
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to add that to my answer when I saw yours

Comment: Its throwing me error   for(i in 1:nrow(trainData)){
 
if (trainData$Age[i]<15) {trainData$Child[i] = 1}
}

Comment: @munishbansal no need to use a `for` loop here. Try one of the answer oncluding `ifelse`.

Comment: what if i wanted couple of else statements?

Comment: @munishbansal this is another question( I hate answer to new questions in comments). But easy to use `nested ifelse`: for example `transform(df,child = ifelse(age<5, 1 ,ifelse(age<10,2,NA)))`

Comment: thnx buddy. I appreciate